# org-agenda-ndays stopped working after package update

Tags: org-mode

the `org-mode-ndays` setting stopped having any effect on my agenda view after updating all packages. I would like to get this working again. :)
When I open the agenda the Week-agenda is shown (should be day-agenda), if I change it to day-agenda
and then refresh I'm back in Week-agenda. This is really annoying but I have no idea how to investigate this issue. Any suggestions?

my setup

```
  (setq org-agenda-custom-commands
        '(("d" "Daily agenda and all TODOs"
           (
            (agenda ""
                    ((org-agenda-ndays 1)
                     (org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'nottodo 'any))))
            )
       )))
```

GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.8) of 2016-10-20

Org mode version 9.0.4 (9.0.4-elpaplus @ /home/ibayer/.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-20170124/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new setting is called `org-agenda-span`. Try:

```
(setq org-agenda-span 'day)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. I spend quite some time trying to figure out what went wrong.